# Issues with character encoding in Wordpress WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, wysiwyg

I've searched for similar questions and found nothing, apologies if I missed them.

The WYSIWYG editor on a Wordpress site I'm working on has strange character encoding. Certain letters are bridged, mainly st and ch, but I think there are others too. See here:

[image: Encoding issues]

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: might just be your font?

Comment: here is the solution: [Strange characters - despite everything being UTF-8](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156626/strange-characters-despite-everything-being-utf-8)

Comment: very similar to this : http://graphemica.com/%EF%AC%86/glyphs/dejavu-serif-book

Comment: @AhsanHaroon that's a very different issue. Stender was closer, seems like it's just the font after all. Embarrassing, oops.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be merely a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) used by the font. Nothing to do with encoding. In fact, the font designer went to great lengths to explicitly put that ligature there.